# How to prove the sequence $a_{n+1}=3a_{n−1} $is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove the sequence $a_{n+1}=3a_{n−1} $is divergent?

It is increasing, however, it does not have a upper bound.
How to prove this?

Comment: That depends on the initial condition.  If $a_0=a_1=0$ then it is clearly convergent as all terms in the sequence are zero.

Comment: It is not increasing if $a_0=3, a_1=1$ for example, and it is not divergent if $a_0=a_1=0$. Is this a repost of your [Determine whether the sequence $a_{n+1} = 3a_n - 1$ is convergent or divergent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204866/determine-whether-the-sequence-a-n1-3a-n-1-is-convergent-or-divergent) by any chance?

Comment: 3^k *a_0 is a subsequence is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

.Note that $a_{2n} = 3^na_0$, $a_{2n+1} = 3^na_1$

Answer (score 1):

You are already on the right track.

If a sequence converges, it must have an upper bound, right, since if $a_n \to L$, then there exists an $n \in N$ s.t. for $n > N$, $|a_n -L| < 1$. Our upper bound is therefore $max(a_1,a_2,.,,a_N, |L|+1)$. You can write the similar proof for lower bound.

So if the sequence does not have an upper bound or a lower bound, it tells us....